# Android theme reset after rotation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, themes

I provide theme option for my app user. But I found the theme will reset back to default theme after rotation. 
Here is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    config = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    theme = config.getString("theme", "");

    setActionBarTheme(theme);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

private void setActionBarTheme(String theme)
{
    if(theme.equals("Holo Red"))
    {
        setTheme(R.style.onTime_Theme_Holo_Red);
    }else
    {
        setTheme(R.style.onTime_Theme_Default);
    }
}
```

**This activity is hosting fragments, when device is rotated, fragment remain but theme reset.**

If device config changed, it should recreate the activity. Is it bug or I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @CBergson pointed out, you can save the theme and recreate it whe the `Activity` is recreated.

On the other hand you can prevent Android from destroying your `Activity` by adding the following line to your *AndroidManifest.xml*:

```
<activity android:name="YourActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"  />
```

Further reading [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config).

Comment: Yeah, i tried. But i prefer allow rotation =D
what do you guys mean save the theme? I already save it to SharedPeferences and load it when activity is created.

Comment: Ok there wasn't code posted, where you save it... I think you missunderstood me, my solution has nothing to do with denying rotation. It just instructs Android to _NOT_ recreate the Activity on rotation. Just try it...

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Yeah, my mistake, your answer works very well. And I search for it on developer doc [activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html). Thank you so much. =D

Answer (score 0):

You should save/update the current theme in your preferences, so that It wont be the default value. Activity life-cycle will repeat itself (stop-destroy-start etc...) when the rotation happens. You need to save it before the cycle is completed before the next activity cycle starts.

Comment: what do you mean save it? I had save the theme as string into SharedPreferences, and load from it every time when the activity is create.

Comment: post your code please. You said, you provided options so users can choose, then where do you save it?

Comment: I save it to default SharedPreference, and the option provide in PreferenceActivity. Now the problem is the theme set correctly when activity started, but it will reset back to default after rotation.

Comment: I think you only save the default. Do you update the theme in your preferences. What do you do when someone choose a different theme? You need to update your default theme variable in your preferences when someone choose a new theme.